# Number of $n$ letter words from letters a,b that contain exactly $m$ substrings "ab"

Tags: combinatorics

I want to prove the number of $n$ letter words that just have letters `a,b` that exactly have $m$ "`ab`" expression is $n+1 \choose 2m+1$

example: $n=3 , m=1$, the result is $3+1 \choose 2\times1+1$=$4 \choose 3$=$4$

which is true : `aba`,`aab`,`bab`,`abb`

I don't know how to attack this problem,because I rarely encounter problems that need proving.
(in combinations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $n+1$ position, numerated as $0, 1, 2, 3,\cdots, n$.

Any string which satisfies the condition will be on the following form("sub" for substring and all underbraced substring repeat its beginning letter)
\begin{align}
\underbrace{b \cdots}_{\text{1st $b$ sub }} \underbrace{a\cdots}_{\text{ 1st $a$ sub }}\underbrace{b \cdots}_{\text{ 2nd $$b sub }} \underbrace{a\cdots}_{\text{ 2nd $a$ sub }} \cdots \underbrace{b \cdots}_{\text{ (m+1)-th $$b sub }} \underbrace{a\cdots}_{\text{ (m+1)-th $a$ sub }} 
\end{align}

where the first $b$ substring and the last $a$ substring may be empty but other substrings are at least of length 1. We only need to choose where the first (2m+1) substrings stop among the $n+1$ positions